# I want useEffect loop

Tags: reactjs, axios

I know that question is unusual but i need to send requests as long i don't get status finished in axios react . I am using useEffect to dispatch action get status end set status via action, useEffect dependency is set [status, dispatch, props] but still its only send 4-5 requests and stop. I also try setTimout on 500 ms but same result. Does anybody have same problem ever?

```js
    const status = useSelector((state: any) => state.reports.status);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        let timer: any = null;
        if (status !== 'FINISH') {
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch(getData(props.id));
            }, 500);
        }
        return () => {
            if (status === 'FINISH') {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
        }
    }, [ dispatch, status, props ])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(false);
const status = useSelector((state: any) => state.reports.status);

useEffect(() => {
    let timer: any = null;
    if (status !== 'FINISHED') {
        dispatch(getData(props.id));
        // setting state after 1s or what you need
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setState(!state);
        }, 1000);
    }
    return () => {
        if (status === 'FINISHED') {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }
}, [ status, getDataFetch, state, dispatch ])
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a state, which basically toggles the value and passe the `state` to the `useEffect` dependency, so the state value changes every time `useEffect` is called until you don't get the status value `finished`, as you can see the below code, I hope this works.

```
const status = useSelector((state: any) => state.reports.status);
const [state, setState] = useState(false);
    
useEffect(() => {
  if (status !== 'FINISH') {
     setState(!state);
     dispatch(getData(props.id));
  }
}, [ dispatch, reportStatus, props, state ])
```

Comment: Sorry , i get : 
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: I used part of your solution, thank you.